# ¿Cómo concatenar valores de checkbox en un input type text?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, html-tabla

Tengo una tabla en `mysql` con alrededor de 15,000 registros de enfermedades, utilizo un buscador para encontrar la enfermedad, todo bien hasta aquí. Quiero agregar un `checkbox` para seleccionar las enfermedades que presenta el paciente ya que pueden ser varias de la tabla, de ser posible que me las muestre en un `<input type="text"/>` concatenando el `id_enfermedad`, o en otra tabla donde pueda ver todos los datos de la patología en la misma página.

Intente agregando un `form` en la tabla donde esta el `checkbox` pero me hace muy lento el llenado de la tabla y solo me muestra en el la caja de texto un dato. ¿Alguien me puede orientar como hacerlo o si tienen un ejemplo mucho mejor.

Este es el archivo `index.php`

```php
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#resultadoBusqueda").html('<p>JQUERY VACIO</p>');
});

function buscar() {
    var textoBusqueda = $("input#busqueda").val();

     if (textoBusqueda != "") {
        $.post("buscar.php", {valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda}, function(mensaje) {
            $("#resultadoBusqueda").html(mensaje);
         }); 
     } else { 
        $("#resultadoBusqueda").html('<p>JQUERY VACIO</p>');
        };
};
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <form accept-charset="utf-8" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="busqueda" id="busqueda" value="" placeholder="" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off" onKeyUp="buscar();" />
    </form>
<div id="resultadoBusqueda"></div>
</body>
```

Este es el archivo `buscar.php`

```php
<?php

require('conexion.php');

$consultaBusqueda = $_POST['valorBusqueda'];

//Filtro anti-XSS
$caracteres_malos = array("<", ">", "\"", "'", "/", "<", ">", "'", "/");
$caracteres_buenos = array("& lt;", "& gt;", "& quot;", "& #x27;", "& #x2F;", "& #060;", "& #062;", "& #039;", "& #047;");
$consultaBusqueda = str_replace($caracteres_malos, $caracteres_buenos, $consultaBusqueda);

$mensaje = "";


if (isset($consultaBusqueda)) {

  $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM enfermedades
  WHERE enfermedad COLLATE UTF8_SPANISH_CI LIKE '%$consultaBusqueda%' 
  OR id_enfermedad COLLATE UTF8_SPANISH_CI LIKE '%$consultaBusqueda%'
  ");

  $filas = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);

  if ($filas === 0) {
    $mensaje = "<p>No hay ningún usuario con ese nombre, apellido, curp o poliza</p>";
  } else {
    echo 'Resultados para <strong>'.$consultaBusqueda.'</strong>';
?>

<table style="width:80%">
  <tr>
    <th>id enfermedad:</th> 
    <th>enfermedad:</th>
    <th>Agregar</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    while($resultados = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
      $id_enfermedad = $resultados['id_enfermedad'];
      $enfermedad = $resultados['enfermedad'];
      ?>
    <td> <?php echo $id_enfermedad ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $enfermedad ?></td> 
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id_enfermedad ?>" name="id_enfermedad">
    </td> 
  </tr>
  };
  }; 
  ?>
```

Comment: gracias! funciona bien con `$('input#busqueda')`, lo que necesito es seleccionar varios `checkbox`, que los agrupe y me los muestre en una caja de texto y saber por que tarda en mostrar los datos si agrego el `<form>` dentro de la tabla donde esta el `checkbox`

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que todos los checkbox sean agrupados con el mismo nombre, tienes que agregar `[]` al nombre asi:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id_enfermedad ?>" name="id_enfermedad[]">
```

Comment: tienes algún ejemplo que me pueda ayudar? por favor, vi un ejemplo donde los datos son con un array definido y si funciona, pero en este caso los tomó de la base de datos.

Comment: gracias! ya logre resolverlo.